# Salesforce Einstein recommendation builder

Tags: salesforce

I have a requirement to see whether the Salesforce Einstein recommendation builder has the functionality of when a user accesses a document, that there is the option for related documents to be recommended.

If anyone has used the Salesforce Einstein recommendation builder for documents please can you advise if the requirement is feasible and how it would work practically